# In Django, how can I prevent a "Save with update_fields did not affect any rows." error?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, sql-update

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have this code

```
article = get_article(id)
...
article.label = label
article.save(update_fields=["label"])
```

Sometimes I get the following error on my "save" line ...

```
    raise DatabaseError("Save with update_fields did not affect any rows.")
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Save with update_fields did not affect any rows.
```

Evidently, in the "..." another thread may be deleting my article.  Is there another way to rewrite my "article.save(...)" statement such that if the object no longer exists I can ignore any error being thrown?

Comment: Have a look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

Comment: You can catch the DatabaseError and check whether article.refresh_from_db() throws Article.DoesNotExist or not to verify the object has been deleted.

Comment: Are you shore that   article.label != label  ?  seems that before and after save data is same

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259032/in-django-how-can-i-prevent-a-save-with-update-fields-did-not-affect-any-rows#comment99134860_56259032) by gachdavit suggested using [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update). You could modify your `get_article` function to call `select_for_update` prior to fetching the article. By doing this, the database row holding the article will be locked as long as the current transaction does not commit or roll back. If another thread tries to delete the article at the same time, that thread will block until the lock is released. Effectively, the article won't be deleted until after you have called the `save` function.

Unless you have special requirements, this is the approach I'd take.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any special way to handle it other than to check to see if the values have changed.

```
article = update_model(article, {'label': label})


def update_model(instance, updates):
    update_fields = {
        field: value
        for field, value in updates.items()
        if getattr(instance, field) != value
    }
    if update_fields:
        for field, value in update_fields.items():
            setattr(instance, field, value)
        instance.save(update_fields=update_fields.keys())
    return instance
```

Edit:
Another alternative would be to catch and handle the exception.

Comment: Hey I tried putting in yoru function but discovered I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I don't think there's a bug in it. Did you try debugging what's running to see what the values are?

Answer (score 2):

This is hacky, but you could override [`_do_update`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fcbc502af93f0ee75522c45ae6ec2925da9f2145/django/db/models/base.py#L881) in your model and simply return `True`. Django itself does something kind of hacky on [line 893](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fcbc502af93f0ee75522c45ae6ec2925da9f2145/django/db/models/base.py#L893) of `_do_update` to suppress the same exception when `update_fields` contains column names that do not appear in the model.

The return value from `_do_update` triggers the exception you are seeing from [this block](https://github.com/django/django/blob/fcbc502af93f0ee75522c45ae6ec2925da9f2145/django/db/models/base.py#L856-L861)

I tested the override below and it seemed to work. I feel somewhat dirty for overriding a private-ish method, but I think I will get over it.

```py
def _do_update(self, base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields, forced_update):
    updated = super(Article, self)._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields, forced_update)
    if not updated and Article.objects.filter(id=pk_val).count() == 0:
        return True
    return updated
```

This solution could be genericized and moved to a mixin base class if you need to handle this for more than one model.

I used this [django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) to test

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from foo.models import Article

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Article.objects.update_or_create(id=1, defaults=dict(label='zulu'))

        print('Testing _do_update hack')
        article1 = Article.objects.get(id=1)
        article1.label = 'yankee'
        article2 = Article.objects.get(id=1)
        article2.delete()

        article1.save(update_fields=['label'])
        print('Done. No exception raised')
```